# Why does sequelize not have a way to handle arrays?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, handlebars.js, mysql2

All my searching led me to doing a get: and set: to do something with the array,
but the error always tells me it's not a string because I set datatype to string.

I also tried every other datatype and it's still telling me it's not any of those things. The documentation says you can have arrays in Postgres but I can't use it for this project.

Comment: Can you show some code? As i can deffinitely say sequelize handles arrays

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.